# Injecting repository from UI seems wrong to me

Tags: c#, architecture, repository-pattern

I am a bit confused about the trend that seems to be going of injecting the repository in the user interface.

I have always built or worked on system where the UI was totally ignorant about the repository layer but would only know about the layer above.

Googling a bit a found a developer who had the same concern as mine see link below

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199799/should-a-repository-be-passed-in-to-the-user-interface

however reading the answers I am still no clear and does not sound good to me that we should inject the repository into the ui.

If I have the following,

```
UI(dll1) --> ServiceGateway(dll2)-> Service(wcf)(dll3)-->BizLayer(dll3)-->Dal(dll3)
```

Why would inject the repository all the way through?

Yeah it's good for mocking but nothing stops a developer calling the repository from the UI directly .It has happened so many times.

Can somebody point to a link or explain why something that used to be bad now is "best practice"?

Comment: Erm, who said it's the best practice? Also, this is kinda opinionanted, not sure if you'll get some definite answer...

Comment: The reason I said "best practice" is because wherever you look they all seems to be doing it.are they doing all wrong then.I guess I will never get a definitive answer

Comment: Can you please provide a reference that highlights this as bad practice? Just because 'they all seem to be doing it' isn't particularly convincing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, I cannot give you a definite answer either, but I do share your concern.

On a recent project for which i set up the database, dal, and part of the bll, the pm was constantly hammering on keeping the data hidden from the UI, and I fully agreed. Then all of a sudden he insisted on injecting the repository from the UI - because that made testing easier.

I was, I guess, as confused as you. 
When I asked what was to keep a developer from accessign the data directly, since he had access to the repository, his answer was "he shouldn't".
So we built a whole framwork with seperate layers to ensure we control data access, only to rely ultimately on "let's hope the developers behave well".

I am all for moving the repository injection as close to the data layer as reasonably possible and certainly not leave that responsibility to the UI.

Comment: No matter what you do, when it comes down to it you are *always* reliant on the developers behaving well.

Comment: @oerkelens You are spot on we have the same concerns.We have big developer teams (150)no chance you can control that!Glad you replied I started to feel "alone" with these spreading bad practice

Comment: @oerkelens Also meant to add that is exactly what my PM said "you must inject the repository from the UI" as he had read a book that they were doing that.Again I will push to move the repository injection as late as possible.

Comment: @Chris Yes, of course you are. But actually leaving a direct access possibility to the data lingering around your UI and expecting them _not_  to use it does seem to be a bit like _asking_  them to misbehave :)

Answer (score 1):

A repository is an abstraction between the UI and persistence. You may need more levels of abstraction than that, or it may be sufficient. It will depend on the application. The important things are that that layer of abstraction exists, that the UI accesses persistence functionality via that abstraction layer and that that layer is injected into the UI, rather than being access via a locator (anti) pattern.

Comment: thanks for your time in answering but still does not answer my question.What is your view?Do you inject the repository from the ui or not.Sorry for being direct but lots words but not clear to me

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by "inject the repository from the ui". You would inject the repository *into* the UI, unless you have other layers involved, in which case you'd inject one of those into the UI instead.

Comment: lets simplify this in a web app or winapp in their bootstrap they instantiate their repositories and inject into wcf service or bizlayer that is what I meant.That seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your WCF service should inject the datasource, as it is a standalone application that just happens to expose data and in that way serves as a DAL for an application built on top of it.

Your website (UI) doesn't care how your service (DAL) gets its data.

In your example, it would only make sense for the UI to injected itself at startup with the `ServiceGateway`. It doesn't (have to) know anything about the service implementation, it merely *calls* the service.

In fact, unless you self-host the WCF service from your UI, you can't even do anything with the service's dependencies from the consuming application: the service has to inject them at *service* startup. Self-hosting in this case can also mean that an ASP.NET website hosts its own services. In that case you'll also find the repository injection for the service in your `Global.asax`, as that is shared between the website and the service (and I still would advise against that).

Comment: not sure I understand your answer(each of my wcf service is a standalone unit)now my question is not about wcf even thought it plays a part .why do people inject repository all the way.It would make sense to me to inject it from the business layer or service layer down no?

Comment: @user I meant you should not inject the repository from the UI. Also, given your WCF services runs as a standalone application, **how** could a consuming application even inject the repository?

Comment: sorry for not being clear.I could have/use unity to inject an interface into my wcf constructor and that way i could mock the biz layer for a start.I seems to get questions instead of answers.May be I asked the wrong thing.Is there anywhere a sample app that use "best practice" all i seem to find is injection of repository everywhere.

Comment: _"I could have/use unity to inject an interface into my wcf constructor and that way i could mock the biz layer for a start"_ - that is correct. You can do so from your WCF Service's `Global.asax` for example. Your UI cannot and should not inject the service's dependencies.

Comment: so why so many people inject their repository interfaces when they should inject just the layer above?